# Python Help please - creating basic functions (Ver 2.7)

Tags: python

I've made progress on this question, but it always returns the first value only in the list. What am I missing in my code?

**Write a function called add_numbers that receives one list parameter. It returns the total of all numbers in the list from the start, until at least 10 is found. If a number greater than or equal to 10 is not found, it returns the sum of all numbers in the list.**

```
def add_numbers(a):

total = 0

i = 0

  while a[i] < 10:

    total = total + a[i]

    i = i + 1

    return total
```

The second one is:

**Write a function called make_list that receives one numeric parameter. It returns a list of the numbers from 0 to one less than the numeric parameter.**

I know how to do this is if asked for the sum of all numbers, but im confused by the list.

Last one is:

**Write a function called count_bricks that receives one numerical parameter. This function returns the number of bricks in a pyramid that is that many levels high. Each level in the pyramid has one more brick than the level above it.**

Not sure where to even start on this one.

Thanks for the help in advance. It's not homework, it's just a sample quiz full of questions - these are the ones I wasn't able to answer.

Comment: Please format the code in your question. I suspect the issue in your first part is related to the position of your `return` statement, but without formatted code, it is hard to tell. Also, is this homework?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: If you can't get indentation right you might want to consider learning a different language. It's not just because it looks nice. It has to be right because it changes the meaning of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put return outside the loop or else the value will be return on the first iteration.

```
def add_numbers(a):
    total = 0
    i = 0
    while a[i] < 10 and i < len(a):
        total = total + a[i]
        i = i + 1
    return total        # return  should be outside the loop
```

Hint for the second question:

1. Create a function that takes one input
2. Return a new list using a built-in function [range( )](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

Add a check to end the loop when the list ends:

```
while a[i] < 10 and i < len(a):
```

**Second problem:**

Read about Python's [lists](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Just loop the times of the number and add the number to a list. Finally return that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_numbers(a):
    """
        returns the total of all numbers in the list from the start, 
        until a value of least 10 is found. If a number greater than 
        or equal to 10 is not found, it returns the sum of all numbers in the list.
    """
    total = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(a):
        total = total + a[index]
        if a[index] >= 10:
            break
        index += 1
    return total
```